# Get current folder within SharePoint document library with @pnp/sp

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, typescript, pnpjs

I need to get the folder name within a document library, within the ListCommand spfx extension. Is there a way to do that with REST ? can I use @pnp/sp ?

I have imported the project with :

```
import { sp } from "@pnp/sp";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below PnPjs code to get all folders from a library and print name and url:

```
import { sp } from "@pnp/sp";

sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Documents").items.filter('FSObjType eq 1').select('FileLeafRef', 'FileRef').get()
.then(folders => {
    folders.forEach(f => {
        console.log('Folder name: ' + f.FileLeafRef);
        console.log('Folder url: ' + f.FileRef);

    })
})
```

`FSObjType` (display name `Item Type`) is a built-in field, values are based on [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.filesystemobjecttype.aspx) enumeration